# Use ffmpeg to stream live content to azure media services

Tags: azure, video, ffmpeg, azure-media-services

I've been trying to stream content to azure media services using ffmpeg as it's one of the options described here : http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/18/azure-media-services-rtmp-support-and-live-encoders/

My command is :

```
ffmpeg -v verbose -i 300.mp4 -strict -2 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -r 30 -g 60 -keyint_min 60 -b:v 400000 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -bufsize 400k -maxrate 400k -f flv rtmp://nessma-****.channel.mediaservices.windows.net:1935/live/584c99f5c47f424d9e83ac95364331e7
```

I have made sure that the streaming endpoint has one active streaming unit, I also made sure that the channel is actually Ready and I even get it to start streaming (which makes a PublishURL available).

When I execute the ffmpeg command to start streaming, I keep getting the following error :

`ffmpeg version 2.5.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 30 2014 11:31:18 with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
  configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libgsm --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx265 --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
  libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Routing option strict to both codec and muxer layer
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9a0a002c00] overread end of atom 'colr' by 1 bytes
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9a0a002c00] stream 0, timescale not set
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9a0a002c00] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5003637 microseconds
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '300.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2014-01-11 05:39:32
    genre           : Trailer
    artist          : Warner Bros.
    title           : 300: Rise of an Empire - Trailer 2
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.9 2013051800
    date            : 2014
  Duration: 00:02:33.24, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7377 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 (1920x1088), 7219 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-01-11 05:39:32
      encoder         : JVT/AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 157 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-01-11 05:39:32
    Stream #0:2: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 101x150 [SAR 72:72 DAR 101:150], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
rtmp://nessma-****.channel.mediaservices.windows.net:1935/live/584c99f5c47f424d9e83ac95364331e7: Input/output error`

The Azure blog post clearly states that this should be possible but I can't find a working example anywhere.

Environment :

- MacOS Maverick
- FFMPEG installed from official build
- 300.mp4 : 1080p trailer of the latest 300 movie

Answer (score 8):

I figured out the missing piece here ...

At the end of the publishURL, you need to add /mystream1 at the end. Hopefully, this helps somebody.

Comment: which also is clearly in the sample at the page you referred.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add stream key name in the end of your ingest url.
In azure stream key name can be anything. It is used for references and logs purpose only.
Ex:

```
rtmp://nessma-****.channel.mediaservices.windows.net:1935/live/584c99f5c47f424d9e83ac95364331e7/some_random_stream_name
```

When people works with azure, they usually use the same stream name every time they broadcast anything. Some people, change stream name to match event name like `"...live/584c99f5c47f424d9e83ac95364331e7/tennis_game_x_against_y"`. When you have a lot of events it will help you with troubleshooting both on your and azure side.